# ActionBarDrawerToggle изменить цвет

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как изменить цвет у навигационного индикатора. Вот мой код, так не работает. Прошу подсказать!

[image]

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,  drawerLayout, newstoolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    );
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu30);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Код из стиля тоже не помогает:

```
  <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="color">@color/colorWhite</item>
...
style>
```

П.С. как сменить саму иконку знаю, интересно с элементом анимации.

UPD. стиль акшен бара:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Привязка в манифесте:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".NewsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.News" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: в основной стиль дописали  <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>? И в манифесте стиль подрубили?

Comment: Не очень понятно - вы хотите стандартную иконку или свою?

Comment: Стандартную, но другого цвета.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Спасибо!!!! Криво привязал. Заработало!

Answer (score 2):

```
Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.menu30);
icon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(icon);
```

Один из вариантов.

Comment: да, так точно работает, спасибо! смысл был немного в другом, поменять не цвет иконки, а стандартный цвет навигатора.